# Comparação simples entre datas

Tags: javascript

Preciso de uma comparação simples entre datas em javascript a data final não pode ser menor que a data inicial. Achei alguns scripts na internet e tentei adaptar para o meu, mas como conheço praticamente nada, não deu certo.

Segue o script que eu estou adaptando.

```
  <script language="javascript">
function checarDatas(){
var form_insere = document.form_insere;

var data_1 = form_insere.datainicial.value;
var data_2 = form_insere.datafinal.value;
var Compara01 = parseInt(data_1.split("/")[2].toString() + data_1.split("/")[1].toString() + data_1.split("/")[0].toString());
var Compara02 = parseInt(data_2.split("/")[2].toString() + data_2.split("/")[1].toString() + data_2.split("/")[0].toString());

if (Compara01 > Compara02) {
   alert("Data não pode ser maior que a data final");
   return false;
}
else {
    return true
}
 }
    </script>
```

coloquei também `onsubmit="return checarDatas()"` na tag form.
O objetivo é quando o usuário digitar uma data inicial (07/05/2014) e depois na data final (06/04/2014) dispare um alerta indicando que as datas estão erradas e não deixe ele submeter o formulário até voltar e corrigir.
Obrigado, e aceito quaisquer tipos de sugestões.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Creio que basta criar objectos data e compará-los.

```
function checarDatas() {
    var form_insere = document.form_insere;

    var data_1 = new Date(form_insere.datainicial.value);
    var data_2 = new Date(form_insere.datafinal.value);
    if (data_1 > data_2) {
        alert("Data não pode ser maior que a data final");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Estas validações podem ser mais ou menos complexas dependendo do que pretende fazer. Sugiro juntar uma verificação para o caso de as datas não terem sido escolhidas. Na sua forma mais simples seria:

```
if (!data_1 || !data_2) return false;
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/RtH3K/1/)

Comment: "Você não pode aceitar uma resposta em 7 minutos" Deu certo sim... Com muito menos código ainda :) Ideia: Tem como ele pegar uma data confiável de algum lugar para que também compare e não coloque as datas no tempo passado? Por exemplo: 05/05/2014 ontem.

Comment: Eu imagino que tenha como ele pegar data do relógio do usuário para esse tipo de comparação, mas teria como burlar se o usuário modificasse a hora de seu local.

Comment: @Vinicius, sim as datas do lado do utilizador estão dependentes do browser e podem ser alteradas pelo usuário. O melhor é usar a hora do lado do servidor.

Comment: porque se colocar um  } else if (data_1 == data_2) { não funciona e cai sempre no else

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo dois objetos data dão sempre diferentes. Ou seja `new Date() == new Date()` dá sempre false.

Comment: e como vou fazer para checar datas iguais?

Comment: se eu colocar >=  no igual funciona

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/67850/129

Comment: mas lá não é input type date

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo input type date dá sempre uma string. Coloca uma pergunta que dou uma ajuda.

Answer (score 5):

Complementando:

Existe uma ótima biblioteca, chamada [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), feita especialmente para tratar de datas/horas/timezones. Dependendo da necessidade de manipulação de datas no seu projeto, ela pode se tornar interessante.

Um exemplo de comparação de datas usando a Moment.js:

```
var agora = moment();
var amanha = moment().add('days', 1);

if (agora < amanha) {
    // alguma coisa
}
else {
    // outra coisa
}
```

Comment: Interessante, nesse projeto existe uma parte onde fica listado os forms com diferentes datas de inicio. Seria bacana mesmo colocar também algo como:
Tal coisa: No próximo sábado, Outra coisa: Daqui duas semanas. Fica esteticamente melhor para visualizar os forms que o usuário quiser.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando a biblioteca moment podemos fazer uma comparação desta forma:

```
let date1 = moment(date_1, "DD/MM/YYYY").format("YYYYMMDD");
let date2 = moment(date_2, "DD/MM/YYYY").format("YYYYMMDD");

if (date2 > date1) {
  return false;
}
return true;
```