# Como comparar duas datas em Javascript ou jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5, datetime

Estou tentando comparar duas datas vindas de campos `text`, transformando-as em objeto `Date`, da seguinte forma (a primeira função é pra formatar o campo `input` com `XX/XX/XXXX`):

```js
function formatar(mascara, documento){
    var i = documento.value.length;
    var saida = mascara.substring(0,1);
    var texto = mascara.substring(i);
    if (texto.substring(0,1) != saida){
        documento.value += texto.substring(0,1);
    }
}

if(new Date('#datafinal') <= new Date('#datainicial'))
{

alert("A data inicial é maior que a data final");
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa"
                       OnKeyPress="formatar('##/##/####', this)" id="datainicial">
<br>
                <input type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa"
                       OnKeyPress="formatar('##/##/####', this)" id="datafinal">
```

Mas não está dando certo. Acho que pode ser pelo formato que chega do `input`, mas não tenho certeza. Dei uma pesquisada no SOen e [existem várias perguntas com muitas respostas](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=compare%20dates%20and%20display%20alert%20jquery&oq=compare%20da&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i59l2j69i60l2.2618j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com%20jquery%20comparing%20dates), mas nenhuma das que vi conseguiu resolver pra mim.

Basicamente, preciso que quando a pessoa acabe de digitar (antes de clicar no botão enviar) retorne um `alert` caso a data final seja menor que a inicial. Alguma luz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sugiro mudares no HTML para `onkeypress` pois dessa maneira o valor do input é passado à função com a a ultima tecla. Com `onkeypress` o value ainda não tem o novo numero.

No JavaScript podes fazer assim:

```
var datainicial = document.getElementById('datainicial');
var datafinal = document.getElementById('datafinal');

function formatar(mascara, documento) {
    var i = documento.value.length;
    var saida = mascara.substring(0, 1);
    var texto = mascara.substring(i);
    if (texto.substring(0, 1) != saida) {
        documento.value += texto.substring(0, 1);
    }
    verificar();
}

function gerarData(str) {
    var partes = str.split("/");
    return new Date(partes[2], partes[1] - 1, partes[0]);
}

function verificar() {
    var inicio = datainicial.value;
    var fim = datafinal.value;
    if (inicio.length != 10 || fim.length != 10) return;

    if (gerarData(fim) <= gerarData(inicio)) alert("A data inicial é maior que a data final");
}
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/3z247n2o/

Uso uma função para converter essa string em data:

```
function gerarData(str) {
    var partes = str.split("/");
    return new Date(partes[2], partes[1] - 1, partes[0]);
}
```

e depois comparo com a lógica que já tinhas:

```
if (gerarData(fim) <= gerarData(inicio))
```

Se quiseres usar a função `verificar()` integrada na noutro código de validação da `form` podes usar assim, dando `return` *true* ou *false*:

```
function verificar() {
    var inicio = datainicial.value;
    var fim = datafinal.value;
    if (inicio.length != 10 || fim.length != 10) return false;

    if (gerarData(fim) > gerarData(inicio)) return true;
    alert("A data inicial é maior que a data final");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Esse script me ajudou muito mesmo, obrigado @Sergio.