# Comparar datas iguais no javascript

Tags: javascript, data

Com referência nessas duas perguntas:

- [Comparação simples entre datas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14943/compara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-simples-entre-datas)
- [Como comparar duas datas em Javascript ou jQuery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67845/como-comparar-duas-datas-em-javascript-ou-jquery)

Preciso comparar as datas e preciso de três distinção entre duas datas, ela sendo **igual** ou **maior** ou **menor** veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
function gerarData(str) {
    var partes = str.split("/");
    return new Date(partes[2], partes[1] - 1, partes[0]);
}

function teste(){
    var data_1 = '03/03/2016';
    var data_2 = '03/03/2016';

    console.log( gerarData(data_1) );
    console.log( gerarData(data_2) );

    if ( gerarData(data_1) === gerarData(data_2) ) {
      alert("Datas iguais com ===");
    }
    else if ( gerarData(data_1) == gerarData(data_2) ) {
      alert("Datas iguais com ==");
    }
    else if ( gerarData(data_1) > gerarData(data_2) ){
      alert("data_1 > data_2");
    } 
    else if ( gerarData(data_1) < gerarData(data_2) ) {
      alert("data_1 < data_2");
    }
    else{
      alert("inconclusivo \n data_1="+gerarData(data_1)+" \n data_2="+gerarData(data_2));      
    }

}
teste();
```

Por que mesmo o `console.log` me mostrando que são iguais ele não entra na condição que faz essa verificação?

Comment: Acho que bastaria juntar um `+` aqui: `return new Date`, ficando `return +new Date`.

Comment: @Sergio por que? Dá uma resposta.

Comment: @bigown feito :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em JavaScript datas são objetos e dois objetos diferentes nunca são iguais.

Daí que `new Date(1456959600000) == new Date(1456959600000)` (usando `==` ou `===`) dá sempre `false`.

Para comparar datas pode converter-se a data para *Timestamp* e nesse caso a comparação em cima seria `true`. Ou seja compararia numeros, o numero de milisegundos da respetiva data. Na prática seria:

```
+new Date(1456959600000) == +new Date(1456959600000)
```

que é basicamente o mesmo que

```
1456959600000 == 1456959600000
```

Um exemplo de código poderia ser:

```
function gerarData(str) {
    var partes = str.split("/");
    return +new Date(partes[2], partes[1] - 1, partes[0]);
}

function teste(data_1, data_2) {
    var a = gerarData(data_1);
    var b = gerarData(data_2);

    var tipo;
    if (a < b) tipo = 'anterior';
    else if (a == b) tipo = 'igual';
    else if (a > b) tipo = 'posterior';
    else tipo = 'inconclusivo'
    return tipo;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/grggk9xb/

#### Sobre o `+`:

No fundo usar `+new Date();` ou usar `new Date().getTime();` gera um numero, timestamp. A razão pela qual o `+` funciona aqui é porque faz uma conversão de tipo do objeto data para um numero. Chama-se operador unitário (ou unário?), em Inglês [`unary plus operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) e o que ele faz é converter o que estiver depois dele num valor numérico. No caso da data faz isso invocando o `.valueOf()`, mas pode ser usado também em Strings com numeros, ou booleanos. Alguns exemplos:

+true // 1
+false // 0
+'20' // 20
+'45deg' // NaN (neste caso misturando letras ele não encontra valor numérico, o parseInt seria uma alternativa)

Leitura interessante sobre o `+` <sup>(em Inglês)</sup>:

- [unary add](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/unary-add/)
- [plus sign javascript](http://frontendplay.com/2013/05/25/plus-sign-javascript/)

Comment: Sergio, você poderia dar uma referência ou explicação do porque usar o `+` ? Qual sua função nesta colocação antes do `new` no código ?

Comment: @devgaspa sim, farei. O + é um atalho de .getTime(), vou juntar isso à resposta daqui a pouco tive de sair para reunião agora.

Comment: @Sergio a minha dúvida maior é porque o `+` resolve isso.

Comment: @bigown dá uma olhada, hoje consegui tempo para explicar melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa utilizar a função getTime() para converter em números, para que entre na condição correta.

**Exemplo:**

```js
function gerarData(str) {
      var partes = str.split("/");
      return new Date(partes[2], partes[1] - 1, partes[0]).getTime();
}

function teste() {
  var data_1 = '03/03/2016';
  var data_2 = '03/03/2016';
  if (gerarData(data_1) === gerarData(data_2)) {
    alert("Datas iguais com ===");
  } else if (gerarData(data_1) == gerarData(data_2)) {
    alert("Datas iguais com ==");
  } else if (gerarData(data_1) > gerarData(data_2)) {
    alert("data_1 > data_2");
  } else if (gerarData(data_1) < gerarData(data_2)) {
    alert("data_1 < data_2");
  } else {
    alert("inconclusivo \n data_1=" + gerarData(data_1) + " \n data_2=" + gerarData(data_2));
  }

}
teste();
```

Comment: Gabriel, o construtor `Date` do JavaScript com string precisa de uma data no formato `mm/dd/aaaaa`. Acredito que por esse motivo ele utilizou o `split`. Tirando isso, o `getTime` irá resolver o problema dele.

Comment: Se você utilizar dessa maneira, o construtor entenderá que você está passando uma string `mm/dd/aaaa` e a data ficará invertida, por exemplo `new Date('04/03/2016')` a objeto data no objeto será `03 de Abril de 2016` e não `04 de Março de 2016` que seria a data esperada.